# Solution of a pde in $H^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

What does it mean that an equation is verified in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$?
For istance what does it mean that the following equation
$$iu_t+\Delta u+g(u)=0$$
in  $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ for all $t$?

Answer (score 0):

It means that
$$\langle iu_t(t), v \rangle + \int_\Omega \nabla u(t) \nabla v + \langle g(u(t)), v \rangle = 0$$
holds for all $v \in H^1(\Omega)$ for all $t$. the angled brackets denote the duality product between $H^{-1}$ and $H^1$.

By the way usually it is for almost all $t$, not all $t$.